# Uncaught TypeError: $input.keydown(...).focus(...).menu is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a problem of menu is not a function issue in autocomplete. I have a input in document and it's act as typeAhead. When I am pressing any button the issue like.. when I console the $input, it's shown as object.

> Uncaught TypeError: $input.keydown(...).focus(...).menu is not a
>   function
>       at new jQuery.autocomplete (jquery.autocomplete.js:129)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (jquery.autocomplete.js:727)
>       at Function.each (jquery.tools.min.js:50)
>       at init.each (jquery.tools.min.js:44)
>       at init.jQuery.fn.autocomplete (jquery.autocomplete.js:725)
>       at loadRTREfFiledLOV (jquery.autocomplete.js:1124)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (jquery.autocomplete.js:1076)
>       at HTMLInputElement.handle (jquery.tools.min.js:75)
>       at HTMLInputElement.o (jquery.tools.min.js:69)

looking for your help on this.

Am using Jquery UI 1.8.21.